# Como colocar condicionales en React para validar un diagnostico?

Tags: reactjs, validación

Estoy haciendo un app en React que mida el IMC de una persona, tengo la operatoria hecha. mi problema es que cuando quiero que condicione el diagnostico (ya sea si alguien esta en peso normal, bajo peso, sobre peso, etc.) no me lo imprime por pantalla, estoy recien empezando en React y no encunetro cual es el problema , por favor si alguien me ayuda. adjuntare mi codigo.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import "./from.css"


export default function From() {

  
// variables para la operacion
  const  [ num, setNum ] = useState({
    peso:0,
    alt:0
  });
// variables para guardar resultado
  const [imc, setImc] = useState();
  
//actualizamos la operatoria y llevamos acabo la logica
  useEffect(() => {
    const {peso, alt}= num;
    setImc(Number(peso)/Number(alt*alt));
  }, [num])
  // metodo para submit o para que arroje resultado
  const result = (event) => {
    const {name,value}= event.target;
    setNum({...num,[name]:value});
  }

  const validate = (imc)=>{
    if(imc < 18.5){
      return ("estas bajo peso")
  } else if(imc < 24) {
    return("normal");
  }else if(imc < 30){
    return("sobrepeso");
}
}
  
  return (
    <div >
     <div className='row'>
     <div >      
      <h1>Peso</h1>
      <h5>en kg por favor, ejemplo :"70"</h5>
    <input  name='peso'  placeholder="indica tu peso" onChange={result} value={num.peso} /> 
      </div>
      <div >
      <h1>Altura</h1>
      <h5>en cm por favor, ejemplo :"1.80"</h5>
    <input  name='alt'  placeholder="indica tu altura" onChange={result} value={num.alt} /> 
      </div>
   <div>
    <h1>IMC</h1>
    <h5>tu IMC es de :</h5>
   <p>{imc}</p>
   </div>
     </div>

     <div>
      <h5>diagnostico</h5>
     <div><h5>{validate}</h5></div>
     </div>
   
    </div>   
      
  )
}
```

PD: este valor que adjunto a continuacion, cuando no hay ningun valor me arroja "NaN", como puedo cambiarlo para que me arroje un 0.

```
    <div>
    <h1>IMC</h1>
    <h5>tu IMC es de :</h5>
   <p>{imc}</p>
   </div>
```